# find() and findOne() methods in MongoDB showing different results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a Mongo database where in the users collection I have just 1 document.
I do a `find()` and a `findOne()` operations using the username filter.
I get what I think is an incorrect result from `find()` operation.

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.10
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings: 
2016-10-20T20:37:32.681-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-10-20T20:37:32.681-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2016-10-20T20:37:32.681-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-10-20T20:37:32.681-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-10-20T20:37:32.681-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-10-20T20:37:32.681-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-10-20T20:37:32.681-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
> use lab2
switched to db lab2
> db.users.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5807ac0765f24dd0660e4332"), "username" : "avtrulzz", "fname" : "Abc", "lname" : "Def", "email" : "test@yahoo.co.in", "password" : "rootuser", "mobile" : NumberLong(1234567890) }
> db.users.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5807ac0765f24dd0660e4332"),
    "username" : "avtrulzz",
    "fname" : "Abc",
    "lname" : "Def",
    "email" : "test@yahoo.co.in",
    "password" : "rootuser",
    "mobile" : NumberLong(1234567890)
}
> if (db.users.find({username : "noSuchUsername"})) {
... print ("Username exists"); 
... } else {
... print ("User does not exist"); }
Username exists
> if (db.users.findOne({username : "noSuchUsername"})) { print ("Username exists");  } else { print ("User does not exist"); }
User does not exist
> if (db.users.findOne({username : "avtrulzz"})) { print ("Username exists");  } else { print ("User does not exist"); }
Username exists
```

> 

See the `find()` operation is returning user exists which is not true. `findOne()` is behaving correctly.[image]

Comment: Are you saying the problem is the with the differences in outputs in the first two queries ( the find() vs. the findOne() ), or the results of the last commands (the if blocks ) ? What about the output makes you think the results are incorrect?

Comment: I think find() should also return "User does not exist" as there is no user by the name "noSuchUsername" does not exist

Answer (score 35, accepted):

First of all, basic difference between `findOne()` and `find()`:

- **`findOne()`** - if query matches, first document is returned, otherwise null.
- **`find()`** - no matter the number of documents matched, a cursor is returned, never null.

So when put in an if condition, `findOne()` can convert to false when it doesn't match any document. As `find()` returns a cursor object and never returns null, will convert to true when put in an if condition.

`find` and `findOne()` return the following for empty collection :

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The pitfall you find yourself in is the rather undocumented conversion from mongo shell objects to booleans in javascript:

*findOne()* returns a **document**, or nil/null/whatever-it-is-called

*find()* returns a **cursor**, which can be empty. But the *object* returned is always defined.

Answer (score 6):

The the [`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.find/) method returns a [`cursor`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/glossary/#term-cursor) which is always `truthy` even if the query criteria does not match any document.

On the other hand, the [`findOne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.findOne) returns the **first document** that matches your query criteria or `null` (JavaScript or the equivalent in your language driver) if there is not any document that matches the specified criteria.

```
> db.dropDatabase()
{ "dropped" : "test", "ok" : 1 }
> var cursor = db.collection.find();
> cursor;
> typeof cursor;
object
> !cursor;
false
> var document = db.collection.findOne();
> document;
null
> typeof document;
object
> !document;
true
```

Answer (score 3):

The find() method will return an array, even if no documents match the search criteria. An empty array still exists, so it will act as truthy.

findOne() will either return exactly one document, or undefined. Undefined, by definition, is a falsy value.

When you know you will be searching for just one document, use findOne() to get a more accurate representation.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe find is not correct candidate for boolean check, even if there is no data it returns an empty cursor which passes as true in boolean

```
if (db.users.find({username : "noSuchUsername"}).toArray().length>0) {
... print ("Username exists"); 
... } else {
... print ("User does not exist"); }
```

or

```
   if (db.users.find({username : "noSuchUsername"}).size()>0) {
    ... print ("Username exists"); 
    ... } else {
    ... print ("User does not exist"); }
```

findOne is working correctly because if no data is found it returns null which passes as false in boolean check.

Answer (score 1):

use `toArray()` if you use find() method.

below 2 are the same :

```
myDoc.findOne()
myDoc.find().toArray()[0]
```