# What is the difference between find and findOne in this case? Why it does not work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this sort of code. When I search find()... It does not work while searching with findOne()... is working. 
Thanks for your answer!

```
const task = await Task.find({_id, owner: req.user._id}) //This does not  work

const task = await Task.findOne({_id, owner: req.user._id}) // This works

router.patch('/tasks/:id', auth, async (req, res) => {
    const updates = Object.keys(req.body) // The opposite is Object.values()
    const _id = req.params.id
    const allowedUpdates = ['description', 'completed']

    const isValidOperation = updates.every((update) => allowedUpdates.includes(update))

    if (!isValidOperation) {
        return res.status(400).send({error: 'Invalid update!'})
    }

    try {
        const task = await Task.findOne({_id, owner: req.user._id})

        if (!task) {
            return res.status(404).send()
        }

        updates.forEach((update) => task[update] = req.body[update])
        await task.save()   
        res.send(task)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send(e)
    }
})
```

Comment: "does not work" isn't useful; please show error messages or more code or whatever.

Comment: Okay, I provided this code. It returns 500 when I use find..... This behavior pretty strange for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40168478/find-and-findone-methods-in-mongodb-showing-different-results dup

Answer (score 0):

at first, you should use the same syntax to show an error when it coming it the no result may be because the condition is[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFhu6.png) not an achievement.